# Can NuGet use per-project package download paths within the same solution?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, projects-and-solutions

Consider this repo/file structure for our solution...

```
Shared Repo (Checked out to D:/Shared/trunk)
    ├───Shared1.dll Project
    └───Shared2.dll Project

App1 Repo (Checked out to C:/Code/App1/Trunk)
    ├───App1 Project (Refs Shared1.dll project)
    ├───App1.dll Project (Refs Shared1.dll and Shared2.dll projects)
    └───App1.sln

App2 Repo (Checked out to C:/Code/App2/Trunk)
    ├───App2 Project (Refs Shared1.dll project)
    ├───App2a.dll Project (Refs Shared1.dll and Shared2.dll projects)
    ├───App2b.dll Project (Refs Shared1.dll and App2a.dll projects)
    └───App2.sln
```

To make working with the code easier, we bring in the Shared projects directly into the application's solutions, meaning for instance if you open App1.sln, this would be your project tree...

```
App1.sln
    ├───Shared1.dll Project
    ├───Shared2.dll Project
    ├───App1 Project (Refs Shared1.dll project)
    └───App1.dll Project (Refs Shared1.dll and Shared2.dll projects)
```

As you can see, the two Shared DLLs are from a separate repository but are included in this solution.  Visual Studio handles this without any issue, prompting you that you are updating multiple repos when you perform a commit against the solution.  That's fine and is exactly what we want.

The issue we're having however is with NuGet.  From what we understand, the NuGet.config (and the hierarchy/precedence of reading/applying them) is relative to the solution file, and therefore the projects' NuGet references are updated accordingly.  This causes issues in that the references to the NuGet packages in Shared1.dll an Shared2.dll are relative to App1.sln when you're working in App1.sln, meaning if someone else is working in App2.sln and hasn't checked out their two trunks relative to each other exactly the same way you have, the references break.

Our work-around for this is to always check out all three trunks into the same folder as siblings, then put the packaging folder as another sibling, adding '../packages' in the NuGet.config next to each solution. This ensures the references never break, but forces the location of the checkouts which can be a problem.

```
C:/Code/
    ├───Shared Trunk
    ├───App1 Trunk
    ├───App2 Trunk
    └───packages
```

However, if we could specify per-project package download locations, we could put the packaging folders relative to the projects themselves meaning it wouldn't matter where you check them out to.  They would always find the packages they need.  Yes, this means that in our example, there would be duplicate package downloads, but space on disk isn't the issue.  Maintenance of the code is.

```
C:/Code/
    ├───Shared Trunk
    │    └─sharedpackages
    ├───App1 Trunk
    │    └─app1packages
    └───App2 Trunk
         └─app2packages
```

Again, what we want is when opening App1.sln, we want packages for Shared1.dll and Shared2.dll to go in 'sharedpackages' folder but packages used by App1 and App1.dll to go in app1packages.

So... is this possible?  Can you specify different NuGet package download paths per project regardless of which solution they are in?

Comment: As you suspected this is not possible. NuGet currently always checks for the NuGet.Config file relative to the solution's directory. So checking out the separate repositories to specified relative directories, as you have done, is probably the only solution.

Comment: If you create a solution for your shared projects, then all your projects will reference a packages folder in its parent. Then you can merge your app and shared projects and they will all use the proper relative reference.

Comment: I thought of that originally, but the issue there is when you bring them back into one solution (App1 for instance) NuGet gets completely screwed up not knowing where to pull things from.  Updates don't work either.

Comment: Hmm.. BTW: what VCS are you using? Subversion, TFS, etc.? Also can you show the actual folder names you're using, or do you actually have "Trunk" in the name? I'm going to see if I can figure out a solution (no pun intended).

Comment: I'm using SVN.  Don't know what else to add except what's above.  Easiest thing to do to replicate this is in your existing repo, create three subfolders, but then check them each out individually to three separate folders on your disk (so you have to check them each in individually. The fact they share the actual same repo is irrelevant.) Check out two of them as siblings, but put the third higher or lower in the hierarchy.  Then put a DLL project in one of the sibling folders, and app projects referencing the DLL project in the other two.  That will show the issue.

Comment: I would convert Shared1.dll and Shared2.dll into nuget packages and would use nuget to distribute those dlls accross the others solutions.

Comment: That doesn't work at all because the entire point of this is to have access to the *source* code so you can work on those DLLs at the same time as the apps.  Look at the structure of App1.sln up top. It references the DLLs' projects, not the DLLs themselves. Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in the same situation as /u/MarquelV.

From my investigation insofar into the options provided by nuget (at least up to ver. 3.5) for tackling this sort of scenario, I concluded that one has to completely ignore the graphical tools for nuget inside Visual Studio (at least as far as installing/restoring packages is concerned) and to also disable automatic package restore (Tools -> Options -> Nuget etc). Then resort to invoking nuget.exe from the command line whenever the need arises to install/restore packages specifying the folder in which the packages should be placed - this point is important because the graphical interfaces for nuget in visual studio are bend on storing packages in a "global" repository (typically right next to the .sln file of the solution).

In my projects I create an .nuget folder coupled with nuget.exe inside each and every project and reference dlls thusly.

Last but not least each and every project needs to restore packages by using nuget via the .csproj like so:

```
 <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
      <Exec Command=".\.nuget\nuget.exe restore  .\packages.config -PackagesDirectory .\packages"/>
 </Target>
```

The thing to take away from all this is that the graphical tools for nuget and the automatic package restoration (Tools -> Options -> Nuget) cannot be relied upon in order to achieve the goals described here.

Comment: I like your 'BeforeBuild' solution to it. Doesn't exactly do what I wanted as like you said, you now can't use the graphical tools so modifying packages can't be done from the command line, but still, it's something so I'm going to mark this as the answer. (That and it's crazy-old now anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced a similar issue. In my case I was combining projects from smaller solutions into a larger one. The projects were still referencing the packages in their subfolders, and I did not want to change those references and break the smaller solutions. I was able to solve it by symlinking the project packages path to the solution-level path.

`mklink /J .\packages ..\packages`

This effectively tricks the project into thinking it is using a more local version of packages when it was actually using the one from the larger solution.

It's not exactly the same situation, but close enough that I hope it can help someone.